# How to show proccess output in text box in other frame using Python tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm trying to write the 'ping' output to a text box that will be 
created in the 'output' tkinter frame
When I press the 'Submit' button while writing the output to file.

*Questions:*

1: Is there a way to place the text box inside the 'output' frame?
2: How can I print lines from files inside the 'output' frame?
3: How can I use threading or multiproccess to display the output in realtime?

*Before clicking 'Submit':*

[image: before clicking Submit]

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess as sub
from multiprocessing import Queue
import os

class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("650x500")
        self.title("Gil Shwartz GUI Project")
        menu = tk.Frame(self, height=250, width=10, relief="solid")
        menu.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill="both", anchor="w")
        container = tk.Frame(self, relief="flat")
        container.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill="y", expand=True)
        output = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Output", height=350, width=70)
        output.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill="both", expand=True)

        menu.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        menu.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = ["Menu", "MainWelcome", "testPing", "PageOne", "PageTwo"]

        self.frames[0] = Menu(parent=menu, controller=self)
        self.frames[1] = MainWelcome(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[2] = testPing(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[3] = PageOne(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[4] = PageTwo(parent=container, controller=self)

        self.frames[0].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[1].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[2].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[3].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[4].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(1)


    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        print(frame)
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

class Menu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Ping Test",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(2))
        button1.config(bg="royalblue2")
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(4))
        button2.config(bg="dark violet")
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit",
                            command=lambda: Menu.terminate(self))
        button3.config(bg="gray40")

        button1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        button2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        button3.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        button1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        button2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
        button3.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)

    def terminate(self):
        exit()

class MainWelcome(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Text 1", bg="yellow")
        label.pack(fill="x", expand=True)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Text 2", bg="yellow")
        label.pack(fill="x")

class testPing(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        urlLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Enter URL : ", padx=5, pady=5)
        urlLabel.pack(anchor="w")
        urlInputBox = tk.Entry(self)
        urlInputBox.pack(anchor="w")
        urlInputBox.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)

        clearFileLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Clear File?", padx=5, pady=5)
        clearFileLabel.pack(anchor="w")

        clearFile = tk.BooleanVar()
        clearFile.set(False)
        clearFileRadioYes = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="yes", value=True, var=clearFile,
                                           command=lambda: self.callback(clearFile.get()))
        clearFileRadioYes.pack(anchor="w")
        clearFileRadioNo = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="no", value=False, var=clearFile,
                                          command=lambda: self.callback(clearFile.get()))
        clearFileRadioNo.pack(anchor="w")

        urlSubmitButton = tk.Button(self, text="Submit",
                                    command=lambda: self.pingURL(urlInputBox.get(),
                                                                 clearFile.get()))
        urlSubmitButton.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, anchor="e")

    def callback(self, clearFile):
        print(clearFile) # Debugging Mode - check Radio box Var.

    def pingURL(self, host, clearFile):

        global r

        file = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/ping.txt'
        text = tk.Text(self, height=5, width=100, wrap=tk.WORD)
        text.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True)
        if clearFile == True:

            with open(file, 'a') as output:
                output.truncate(0)
                sub.call(['ping', f'{host}'], stdout=output)

        else:

            with open(file, 'a') as output:
                sub.call(['ping', f'{host}'], stdout=output)

        output.close()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", bg="red")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to page 2",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(2))
        button.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", bg="blue")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(1))
        button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = GUI()
    app.mainloop()
```

*After clicking 'Submit':*

[image: After clicking Submit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to make the output frame available or else you can't access it later:

```
self.output = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Output", height=350, width=70)
self.output.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill="both", expand=True)
```

Then, in the `testPing()` class `pingURL()` method you can pack the `Text()` widget in the output labelframe:

```
text = tk.Text(self.controller.output, height=5, width=100, wrap=tk.WORD)
```

I don't know about using threading or multiproccess. In general I think you will get a better response if you post questions for each of your problems instead of listing them in the same question.

Comment: Thank you! this made me understand abit more about the gui design!
although can you explain what the wrap=tk.WORD does? and what a wrapper does? for some reason i can't understand google's answers on that.

Comment: `tk.WORD` is a constant containing the string "word", so the statement is really `wrap="word"`. For a text widget you can control how it will react if a string is longer than a line by specifying `wrap`, which can be any of: "word", "char" or "none". None will not wrap strings over several lines, word will try to wrap the line at a whitespace character and char will wrap at the text widget width. Have a look at [The Tkinter Text Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) which explains a lot. Also see [Py In My eye](https://pyinmyeye.blogspot.com/2012/08/tkinter-text-styles-demo.html).

Comment: **effbot.org** is taking a break. **The Tkinter Text Widget** now resides at [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20190612074239/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm).